# How can I wire a stone saw and power feed motor with a main switch and subordinate feed switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, saw

I have a rock slab saw with a power feed that needs to be rewired.  It has a 1.5 hp motor as the power source for turning the blade, and a small 4 RPM motor to run the power feed.  It needs to be wired so the on/off switch turns on both the saw and the power feed, but with a second switch to shut off the power feed, enabling the saw to run whether the power feed is running or not.  Because I have a hard time with electricity, I'm hoping someone can draw an easy to understand wiring diagram so I can get this saw running...?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure anyone who has "a hard time with electricity" should be wiring power tools, but here's a basic representation. Be sure you're properly considering wire size, grounding, switch ratings, circuit protection, and all the other things that matter when dealing with deadly current.

```
     Hot          Neutral
     ||             |
     ||             |
 [main switch]      |
   ||    ||         |
   ||    ||         |
 [saw]   ||         |
   |     ||         |
   | [feed switch]  |
   |     ||         |
   |     ||         |
   |   [feed]       |
   |______|_________|
```